# Using properties of a class on a generic object

Tags: c#

essentially what I am trying to do is the following : 
I have a class called Animals that reads some animals that has several properties associate with it such as age,type,birth date etc.
What I'm facing problem with is the CompareTo() method which takes a generic object as a parameter, checks if it's of the type Animal and if so compares the name associated with this object to the instance of the name associate with the instance of the Animal.

I tried using

```
this.Name.CompareTo(object.Name);
```

but obviously it doesn't work for this case since Name isn't defined within object.Is there a way around this ? Being able to compare properties inside an object, knowing that it is of type Animal, to properties within an instance of the Animal class ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to reword your question, I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Plus, it won't help anyone in the future if they search for this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `as` operator to cast the object to an `Animal`. If the cast succeeded, then you can compare the name properties. If the cast failed, the object will be null (and you normally return 1 if the other object is null).

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as Animal;

    if (other == null) { return 1; }
    if (this.Name == null) return (other.Name == null) ? 0 : -1;
    return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `object` to an `Animal` before comparing the names:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (obj is Animal)
    {
        Animal other = (Animal)obj;
        return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }

    return 1;  // or whatever behavior you want if obj is not an Animal
}
```